# Call to undefined method App\Models\Catering::search()

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get searching working but i get this error: BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method App\Models\Catering::search().

**CateringController**

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Catering;

class CateringController extends Controller
{
    function query(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->has('search')) {
            $search = Catering::search($request->search)->get();
        } else {
            $search = Catering::get();
        }

        return view('search.index', [
            'search' => $search
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Catering model**

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Catering extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

**web.php**

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\CateringController;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/search/query',[CateringController::class,'query']);
```

**search.index**

```xml
<h1>Search Catering list</h1>

<form  action="/search/query" method="GET">
  @csrf
  <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search...">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td> Id</td>
    <td> Facility name</td>
    <td> Tag</td>
    <td> Location</td>
    <td> Creation date</td>
    <td> Edit</td>
    <td> Delete</td>
  </tr>
  @foreach($devices as $device)
    <tr>
      <td> {{$device['id']}}</td>
      <td>{{$device['nameCatering']}}</td>
      <td>{{$device['tag']}}</td>
      <td>{{$device['location']}}</td>
      <td>{{$device['creation_date']}}</td>
      <td><a href={{"edit/".$device['id']}}>Click to edit</a></td>
      <td><a href={{"delete/".$device['id']}}>Click to delete</a></td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
</table>
<br>
<br>
<a href="addCatering"><button>Make new Catering Facility</button></a>
```

Thanks for your time and answer!

Comment: `undefined method App\Models\Catering::search().` is telling you there is no function named `search` in `Catering`. Laravel doesn't provide that function.

Comment: Out of curiosity, was there some documentation or tutorial that you were following that said to use `::search()`? There may be an external package or something that introduces this functionality, but by default, Laravel uses `where()` to match Query conventions.

Comment: But in Catering.php is only `class Catering extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;
}` What should i do then?

Comment: @TimLewis Yes it was a youtube tutorial. I used the below code from DALI RICHARD HILLARY. But i am getting: Undefined variable: search error

Comment: @TimLewis Do you know what i can do now?

Comment: You'd have to define `$search` as `$search = $request->input('search');`; `$search` and `$this->search` are not defined. That's basic PHP variable stuff though. Also, don't copy code from Stackoverflow verbatim and expect it to work; take a look at it first, and use an IDE that will identify those issues.

Comment: @TimLewis The last error is `@foreach($devices as $device)` $devices is undefined inside my above `search.index` Do you know what i can do here?

Comment: You're not passing `$devices` to the view, so of course it's undefined. `return view('search.index', ['search' => $search, 'devices' => $devices'])`, but you'd have to define `$devices` as `$devices = Catering::where(...);`. Please stop asking questions in the comments and read the documentation first; all of this is well Documented in Laravel.

Comment: You don't seem to be using the `$search` variable anywhere. Perhaps you meant `foreach ($search as $device)` ?

Comment: I figured it out thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use orWhere methond of laravel models

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Catering;

class CateringController extends Controller
{
    function query(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->has('search')) {
            $search = Catering::where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")
                ->orWhere('updated_at', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")
                ->orWhere('location', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")
                ->orWhere('tag', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")
                ->get();
        } else {
            $search = Catering::get();
        }

        return view('search.index', [
            'search' => $search
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am now getting an error: $devices is undefined. How do i fix this?

Comment: I figured it out thank you